# what is google wave?

Tags: php, google-wave

and does anybody even use it? lol.  I mean little over two years ago, google was hyping this thing like crazy, now it's history, a thing in the past, finished!  What happend to it, and who even uses it lol?

Comment: Ever considered googling for it? ;)

Comment: i'm using it and i thing it works great, very usefull. http://www.google.com/support/wave/bin/answer.py?answer=1083134

Comment: I'm in the same situation as Dalen :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is googles atempt at a collaboral tool working as a mix between Chat and mail.
http://wave.google.com